Is mangento 2 support module excluding from JS bundling (like stripe)
I recently enabled JS bundling for my store, which caused the Stripe module not to load in my browser, resulting in the payment button not appearing on my page. Although I updated both the Stripe module and the theme, the issue remains unresolved, and I encountered the following error afterward. If i disable the bundling module load correctly.
core.min.js:57 Unable to resolve dependency {name: 'StripeIntegration_Payments/js/stripe_payments_express', parents: Array(1), deps: Array(0), cb: undefined, run: ƒ, …}

Please help me and let me know any other data needs.
